# Fail to add controller using Entity Framework Web API VS 2013 Express for Web

Tags: c#, entity-framework, rest, asp.net-web-api

Just installed VS 2013 Express for Web and thought that I should try out some of the many tutorials.
This one: [create a rest api with attribute routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/create-a-rest-api-with-attribute-routing)

When I come to the place (Add a Web API Controller) where you should add a controller I get an unexpected error saying:

> There was an error running the selected code generator: 'Method failed with unexpected error code 1337.'

Searching for this error message points to threads here but I haven't found a solution/explanation yet.

Answer (score 0):

Trying these options solved my problem

1- select 'Update Model from Database' just do any changes there (add-remove-update)

2- if possible rename 'Entity Container Name (if possible)!

After that rebuild your solution again ,hope this help you

[image]